# How will I read the whole file with double quotes between and I can't do it manually as I am reading attachments from email

Tags: php, email, readfile

**I am able to read the following with escape sequence:**

```
<?php
htmlspecialchars("<li><a href='index.php'>We are learning php</a></li>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo "Only HTML special characters : ".htmlspecialchars($convert);
?>
```

**But how will I read the whole file with double quotes between?**

```
htmlspecialchars("<li><a href="index.php">We are learning php</a></li>", ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: Please use correct Markdown formatting, don't just put everything in comments.  Also put the question in the question text not just the title.  Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: what r u even saying,  i just gave example asking about my doubt, i am reading the attachments from email as junk files and i wnt to read it properly with escape sequence, i dono how it is done

Comment: Use outer single quotes?

Comment: dats not possible, i am reading email and how will dat be possible manually.. i am reading the atttachments in junk files